# Getting lat lon from geocodefarm using php

Tags: php, json

This is the endpoint - https://www.geocode.farm/v3/json/forward/?addr=WC2H%208LG&country=uk&lang=en&count=1

I want extract lat and lon from the json output using php.

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.geocode.farm/v3/json/forward/?addr=WC2H%208LG&country=uk&lang=en&count=1";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
if(!$json) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$results = $data['geocoding_results']['RESULTS'];
$data = $results->COORDINATES->Latitude[0];
print_r ($data);
?>
```

I am getting a

> Notice: "Trying to get property of non-object in" error

`$result` outputs the `array`.
The error is at getting the latitude off the array.

Comment: paste the output of `$data`

Comment: I am getting a Notice: "Trying to get property of non-object in" error

Comment: Ohh, Ok  `print_r($json)`

Comment: Here you go - https://pastebin.com/is0HDUnj  (print_r $json)

Comment: And this is for print_r($result) - https://pastebin.com/NXU61acg

Comment: Hey @coderaspien check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test according to your output.

```
$json = 

'    { "geocoding_results": { "LEGAL_COPYRIGHT": { "copyright_notice": "Copyright (c) 2017 Geocode.Farm - All Rights Reserved.", "copyright_logo": "https:\/\/www.geocode.farm\/images\/logo.png", "terms_of_service": "https:\/\/www.geocode.farm\/policies\/terms-of-service\/", "privacy_policy": "https:\/\/www.geocode.farm\/policies\/privacy-policy\/" }, "STATUS": { "access": "FREE_USER, ACCESS_GRANTED", "status": "SUCCESS", "address_provided": "WC2H 8LG", "result_count": 1 }, "ACCOUNT": { "ip_address": "217.70.180.226", "distribution_license": "NONE, UNLICENSED", "usage_limit": "250", "used_today": "9", "used_total": "9", "first_used": "06 Jul 2017" }, "RESULTS": [ { "result_number": 1, "formatted_address": "London WC2H 8LG, UK", "accuracy": "UNKNOWN_ACCURACY", "ADDRESS": { "admin_2": "Greater London", "admin_1": "England", "postal_code": "WC2H 8LG", "country": "United Kingdom" }, "LOCATION_DETAILS": { "elevation": "UNAVAILABLE", "timezone_long": "UNAVAILABLE", "timezone_short": "Europe\/London" }, "COORDINATES": { "latitude": "51.5153684402766", "longitude": "-0.12855210617794" }, "BOUNDARIES": { "northeast_latitude": "51.5153684402766", "northeast_longitude": "-0.12855210617794", "southwest_latitude": "51.5140174197844", "southwest_longitude": "-0.12981378029212" } } ], "STATISTICS": { "https_ssl": "ENABLED, SECURE" } } }';

$json = json_decode($json);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json->geocoding_results->RESULTS[0]->COORDINATES);
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [latitude] => 51.5153684402766
    [longitude] => -0.12855210617794
)
```

For getting lat and long

```
$json->geocoding_results->RESULTS[0]->COORDINATES->latitude
$json->geocoding_results->RESULTS[0]->COORDINATES->longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error probably due to `$data = $results->COORDINATES->Latitude[0];`

That will not have any property when the address you have passed in url is not found by google and (and so lat long are not found) that object will be empty.

So you will try with another proper address, you will not get this error.